# How to show error bars in scatter plots using R

Tags: r, scatter-plot, standard-error

SO i have data similar to this

```
Value   Number
3   1.5
6   1.67
9   1.7
12  1.6
15  1.7
18  1.8
21  1.9
24  1.98
27  1.98
30  1.8
33  1.84
36  1.5
39  1.7
42  1.9
45  1.9
48  2.0
51  1.21
54  1.4
57  2.34
60  2.5
63  2.1
66  1.77
```

How would I make a scatter plot with standard error bars....I looked it up and it appears to go something like this

```
errbar(df$Value, df$Number, yplus, yminus, cap = 0.015,
       xlab= deparse(substitute(x)),
       ylab= deparse(substitute(y)))
```

However I am unfamiliar with yplus, yminus? and deparse??
are there other ways to do this? I tried using ggplot and downloaded it using install.packages(ggplot2) but R kept saying it cant find it and tried it with this code

```
> ggplot(data=dataset,aes(x=df$Value,y=df$Number,colour=Code,linetype=Group,ymin=Mean-SE,ymax=Mean+SE)) 
Error: could not find function "ggplot"
> + geom_line()
Error: could not find function "geom_line"
> + scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,2))
Error: could not find function "scale_x_continuous"
> + scale_linetype_manual(values=c(2,1))
Error: could not find function "scale_linetype_manual"
> + geom_point()
Error: could not find function "geom_point"
> + geom_errorbar(width=.1,position='dodge')
Error: could not find function "geom_errorbar"
```

Also how should I go about plotting at 2 scatter plots in one graph with the same values for the x axis and also show the error bars?
Thanks guys...any suggestion would be appreaciated

Comment: Are you familiar with `?library`?

Answer (score 4):

The error you see is because the `ggplot2` package has not been loaded. Adding `library(ggplot2)` to the script would fix this. This is of course assuming the `ggplot2` package is installed. If not, use `install.packages("ggplot2")` to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use R's `gplots` package which is quite nice and easy to handle (in my opinion, at least).

```
# Required package
library(gplots)

# Sample data
x <- seq(3, 66, 3)
y <- c(1.5, 1.67, 1.7, 1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9,  1.98,  1.98,  1.8,  1.84,  
       1.5,  1.7,  1.9,  1.9,  2.0,  1.21,  1.4,  2.34,  2.5,  2.1,  1.77)
xy <- data.frame(x, y)

# Plotting
plotCI(x, y, 
       uiw = .5, gap = 0, pch = 22, pt.bg = "green")
```

Of course, you have to replace arguments `uiw` and `liw` with your error vectors.

Cheers, Florian